# Binding Validation and SaveCommand in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, data-binding

I have several `TextBox` bound to properties.
These properties are tested by Validation.ErrorTemplate.
I don't use MVVM.

**I have added a button in order ta save my input :**

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource BoutonRessourcesTpl}" Command="Save">
  <Button.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Save"  Executed="Save_Executed" CanExecute="Save_CanExecute"/>
  </Button.CommandBindings>
  <Image Source= "Toolbar_Valider.png" Height="16"/>
</Button>
```

In my code behind i wrote this :

```
    private void Save_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void Save_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = IsValid(sender as DependencyObject);
    }

    private bool IsValid(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        // The dependency object is valid if it has no errors, 
        //and all of its children (that are dependency objects) are error-free.
        return !Validation.GetHasError(obj) &&
            LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(obj)
            .OfType<DependencyObject>()
            .All(child => IsValid(child));
    }
```

My problem is that I don't know where call my code for the saving the input.

Answer (score 0):

You put the code in the Save_Executed function. For an example, see : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding.aspx . Although in that example, the CommandBinding is placed on the owner window of the Button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I tried to put a MessageBox in the Save_Executed fonction, and the MessageBox never appear ! In addition, the isValid return true ! So why, the Save_Executed is not executed ?

Comment: Did you try to put the CommandBinding in the Window containing the button, like in the example?